# Difference between salted hash and keyed hashing?

Tags: hash

A cryptographic [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is additional input other than message itself for a hash function so that it prevents attacker from launching dictionary attacks . Usually the salt is stored along with the hash of say the password etc.

Keyed Hashing is secret key is used as input for hashing along with message like HMAC .

Now is there a difference between salted hash and keyed hash ?

Comment: A key is secret, a salt is not.

Comment: [Same question, different era of SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2218924/589259)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keyed hashing is usually used to build message authentication codes (MACs), the most common of which is the hashed-based MAC (HMAC).

MACs are basically cryptographic checksums. They are used to detect when an attacker has tampered with a message. Therefore they require a secret key (to be withheld from an attacker) and should be as fast as possible (to reduce overhead).

Salted hashing has a completely different purpose, which you noted. Because they are intended to deter brute-force attacks, they are intentionally designed to be slow. Also, as you said, salts are not assumed to be secret.

You can build a salted hash out of a MAC by using [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), which basically applies the MAC a lot of times (to make it slower).

Comment: It sounds like with salted hashing, the salt isn't secret (ex. frameworks like http://www.passportjs.org/ that store the salt concatenated to the hash) because it doesn't need to be. If the only way to figure out the password is through brute forcing, then having access to the salt won't help them. This means that if HMAC relies on a secret instead of a salt, it would be vulnerable to a secret being leaked unless it also uses a salted hashing technique in addition to the secret to safeguard against brute force attacks too. I wonder if they do that.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that the salt is not assumed unknown to the attacker, but the key is. An additional difference is that salts are supposed to vary; if you hash three passwords within the same system, then you should use three distinct salt values, whereas keys are reused.

Another way of seeing salts is to consider that you do not have *one* hash function, but a *complete family*. The "salt" is then a designation for the actual hash function that you are using on a specific instance. Each instance should use its own hash function, i.e. its own salt value, to deter attack parallelism (precomputed tables can be thought of as a kind of parallelism), precisely because all the hash functions in the family are public and the attacker knows which one you are using.

Conversely, if you can keep the salt "secret" then it is a key, and can be shared between instances; but since the security model is no longer the same, it is not guaranteed that a salt which is good *as a salt* would ensure security *as a key*. For instance, suppose a system where the salt is the concatenation of a unique server identifier (say, the server [fully qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)) and the current time expressed in milliseconds since a conventional epoch (we assume that no two salts are generated within the same millisecond, and that time management ensures a monotonic clock even if the clock is reset or adjusted). This yields good salts: such salts are unique worldwide (unique across all instances of all servers in the world) and efficient at preventing parallel attacks. However, as keys, they would be extremely poor because the server's hostname and the current time are public information, and the attacker knows them.